# Login function not working

Tags: javascript, php, authentication

Okay so i made a login button and this is the function code, But it keeps showing the error " Login unsuccessful, Please try again... "
Thank you in advance...
I didn't really get what you were asking for so i put almost all the code in cause i am trying and trying and can't figure it out...

```
<?php
include_once ("php_includesss121/check_login_statusopop.php");

// If user is already logged in, header that user away

if ($user_ok == true)
    {
    header("location: user.php?u=" . $_SESSION["username"]);
    exit();
    }

?><?php

// AJAX CALLS THIS LOGIN CODE TO EXECUTE

if (isset($_POST["e"]))
    {

    // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE

    include_once ("php_includesss121/db_conxx12.php");

    // GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES AND SANITIZE

    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
    $p = md5($_POST['p']);

    // GET USER IP ADDRESS

    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));

    // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING

    if ($e == "" || $p == "")
        {
        echo "login_failed";
        exit();
        }
      else
        {

        // END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING

        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $db_id = $row[0];
        $db_username = $row[1];
        $db_pass_str = $row[2];
        if ($p != $db_pass_str)
            {
            echo "login_failed";
            exit();
            }
          else
            {

            // CREATE THEIR SESSIONS AND COOKIES

            $_SESSION['userid'] = $db_id;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $db_pass_str;
            setcookie("id", $db_id, strtotime('+30 days') , "/", "", "", TRUE);
            setcookie("user", $db_username, strtotime('+30 days') , "/", "", "", TRUE);
            setcookie("pass", $db_pass_str, strtotime('+30 days') , "/", "", "", TRUE);

            // UPDATE THEIR "IP" AND "LASTLOGIN" FIELDS

            $sql = "UPDATE users SET ip='$ip', lastlogin=now() WHERE username='$db_username' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
            echo $db_username;
            exit();
            }
        }

    exit();
    }

?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Log In</title>
            <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
                    <script src="js/mainopop.js"></script>
                    <script src="js/ajaxopop.js"></script>
                    <script>
                      function emptyElement(x){
                      _(x).innerHTML = "";
                    }
                      function login(){
                       var e = _("email").value;
                       var p = _("password").value;
                         if(e == "" || p == ""){
                      _("status").innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
                        } else {
                      _("loginbtn").style.display = "none";
                        _("status").innerHTML = 'Please wait...';
                      var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "login.php");
                      ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                      if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                      if(ajax.responseText == "login_failed"){
                        _("status").innerHTML = "Login unsuccessful, Please try again...";
                      _("loginbtn").style.display = "block";
                    } else {
                      window.location = "user.php?u="+ajax.responseText;
                    }
                           }
                            }
                    ajax.send("e="+e+"&p="+p);
                    }
                    }
                </script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <?php
include_once ("template_pageTopLoginPageopop.php"); ?>
                    <div id="pageMiddle">
                        <h2>Welcome ...</h2>
                        <h3>Log In Here</h3>
                        <!-- LOGIN FORM -->
                        <form id="loginform" onsubmit="return false;">
                            <div>Email Address:</div>
                            <input type="text" id="email" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="300">
                                <div>Password:</div>
                                <input type="password" id="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="100">
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    <button id="loginbtn" onclick="login()">Log In</button>
                                    <p id="status"></p>
                                    <a href="forgot_passopop.php">Forgot Your Password?</a>
                                </form>
                                <!-- LOGIN FORM -->
                            </div>
                            <?php
include_once ("template_pageBottomopop.php");
 ?>
                        </body>
                    </html>
```

And Javascript file ajaxopop.js:

```
function ajaxObj(meth, url) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open(meth, url, true);
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return x;
}

function ajaxReturn(x) {
    if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well.. Something goes wrong in login.php

Comment: You need to provide your code in login.php

Comment: This is in login.php @MHakvoort

Comment: @tj1111 you need to provide the code in login.php that handle the ajax call

Comment: We need the php code that handles the login in login.php, please add code additions to the original post where it can be formatted properly :)

Comment: Did you check the username and password which you are giving in the form exists in the database ?

Comment: yes... @phpfresher but it keeps showing the error

Comment: Which if returns the login_failed? The first (checking if the parameters are empty) or the second?

Comment: @MarkusMüller second which is Login unsuccessful, Please try again...

Comment: @tj1111 post your table structure with some sample data.

Comment: username VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
      email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      password VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
      gender ENUM ('m','f') NOT NULL,
      website VARCHAR(255) NULL,
      userlevel ENUM('a','b','c','d') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'a',
      avatar VARCHAR (255) NULL,
      ip VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      signup DATETIME NOT NULL,
      lastlogin DATETIME NOT NULL,
      notescheck DATETIME NOT NULL,
      activated ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (id),
      UNIQUE KEY username (username,email)
@ApulGupta sorry can't format it

Comment: Can you check in console's network tab if ajax request has all valid parameters? Also, can we use jQuery as your existing JavaScript code is messy.

Comment: Post it in an update to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `password` in DB Table should be `md5`
encrypted as  in PHP, you are encrypting it to match further. If not, just remove `md5` encryption from PHP Code.

Comment: More importantly, don't use simple  `md5` like that at all, it is not secure.